# how to pass a function through the constructor in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to pass a function through constructor to my custom `textformfield`
what i am gonna write in class property and textformfield onChanged function and  put them together?
i've already tried this
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyValueChanger extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Press me'),
        onPressed: () => );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyValueChanger()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since pressing something or having a value change is a very common occurrence, you can use the predefined classes and types, in this case: `ValueChanged<>` and for your case: `ValueChanged<String>`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyValueChanger extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<String> onValueChanged;

  const MyValueChanger({this.onValueChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Press me'),
        onPressed: () => this.onValueChanged('NEW VALUE'));
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyValueChanger(
              onValueChanged: (value) => print('Value changed to: $value')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This actually should work straightforward. Just put the function passed in the constructor as the parameter for your TextFormFields onSave function.

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomTextFormField(onSaved: (text)=> doWhatever(text),);
  }
}

class CustomTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {

  Function(String) onSaved;

  CustomTextFormField({@required this.onSaved});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(onSaved: onSaved,);
  }
}
```

If the functions you want to pass get more complicated, you might want to use Dart typedefs. (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive callback from a function. You will need to create a function like this

```
 final Function(String) onChange;
```

i'm having issue on how to pass function as parameter because i'm new to dart language.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
class customAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData leftIcon;
  final IconData rightIcon;
  final Function(String) leftCallBack;
  CustomAppBar(IconData leftIcon, IconData rightIcon, Function leftCallBack): this.leftIcon= leftIcon, this.rightIcon = rightIcon, {this.leftCallBack = leftCallBack};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
        left: 25,
        right: 25,
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: leftCallBack !=null ? ()=> leftCallBack!() : null,
              child: buildIcon(leftIcon),
          ),
          buildIcon(rightIcon),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildIcon(IconData icon) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Icon(icon),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
caller:
catTree = CatTree(onChangeCat: _onChangeCat);
'''
  _onChangeCat(int catId) {
    //
    debugPrint('_onChangeCat callback!');
  }

UI:
class CatTree extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int catId) onChangeCat;
  CatTree({this.onChangeCat});
}

STATE:
class _CatTreeState extends State<CatTree> {
.....

>>>this.widget.onChangeCat(e.id);
}
```